# Savon - shortcut for prepending every element with namespace? (SOAP)

Tags: ruby, api, soap, soap-client, savon

I'm currently building a SOAP client in Ruby, using Savon, but when I write the code to generate the XML, I'm having to write:

```
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.ns :request do
    builder.ns :Foo do
        builder.ns :FooBar do
            builder.ns :Bar, "Foo"
        end
    end
end
```

to generate

```
<ns:request>
<ns:Foo>
<ns:FooBar>
<ns:Bar>Foo</ns:Bar>
</ns:FooBar>
</ns:Foo>
</ns:request>
```

Which is obviously quite repetitive, and I'd like to cut out the NS repetitions if possible. I've also noticed that without the ns, I'm allowed to use curly brackets, rather than dos/ends.

Is there any way around this? I don't like not having the ability to use curly brackets, and when I add dynamic input of element names later, it could make things complicated.

I tried

```
def send_builder(requestsym, data=nil)
@@builder requestsym, data
end
```

But my knowledge of blocks/procs/lambdas isn't good enough to make that work with nested elements.

Comment: Please tell me something, you are trying to build the XML of your request right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need, so you want to prepend a namespace in your request xml right?:

With Savon you can add namespace to your xml request as follows

```
client = Savon.client do
   wsdl: "http://www.webserviceurl.net/service.asmx?WSDL"
   namespace_identifier: :ns
end
response = client.call(:yourOperationHere, message: { request: { foo: { foo_bar: { bar: "Foo" } } } })
```

The result would be (the body of your request):

```
<ns:request>
  <ns:foo>
    <ns:fooBar>
      <ns:bar>
        Foo
      </ns:bar>
    </ns:fooBar>
  </ns:foo>
</ns:request>
```

Just as a note for you, Savon has something called Gyoku, it converts symbols to :camelcase, so if your request is caseSensitive use strings instead of symbols.

Comment: Hi, sounds good, but I'm not sure if I'm screwing something up. When I try that code, I get 

    `NoMethodError: undefined method 'request' for #<Savon::Client:0x007f3e82fb8840>
from (pry):1:in '<main>'`

Comment: it seems something is wrong with your client, what happens when you do `client.wsdl.soap_actions`? Make sure the url of your request is correct, the url I gave you in the answer is just an example

Comment: Hi, I get NoMethodError: undefined method `wsdl' for #<Savon::Client:0x007fbaa0224590

When following your code exactly (passing the new client a string rather than wsdl: 'wsdllocation' ) I get 

Savon 2 expects a Hash of options for creating a new client and executing requests.
Please read the updated documentation for version 2: http://savonrb.com/version2.html

Comment: You may be right, I updated my answer take a look again. But first of all try your requests if they are working with http://www.soapui.org/about-soapui/what-is-soapui-.html

Comment: This is the best answer I have found related to SAVON namespaces, thanks!

Comment: In my case the above was only adding the namespace prefix to the root element. I needed to add `element_form_default: :qualified` to get every element prefixed with namespace